# json encode returns non-json object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I used $.ajax to check data on my controller. It works fine if there's no process before the variables that I put to array for json encoding. 
The controller echoes the data but the view doesn't render it as json encoded data.
Controller:

```
public function redeem($item){
    $this->load->model('point_model');
    $cost = 0;
    switch($item){
        case 'umbrella':
            $cost = 100;
            break;
        case 'jacket':
            $cost = 200;
            break;
        case 'mug':
            $cost = 50;
            break;
    }
    $tixD = $this->point_model->getTicks($_SESSION['playerID']);
    $tix = $tixD[0]->pticks;
    if($tix < $cost){
        $this->load->model('prize_model');
        $this->prize_model->setPrize($item,$_SESSION['playerID']);
        $newTix = $tix - $cost;
        $yes = $this->point_model->updateTicks($newTix,$_SESSION['playerID']);
        if($yes){
            $message = 'Ready to redeem your '.$item;
            $code = 900;
        }
    }else{
        $message = 'Insufficient tickets.';
        $code = 911;
    }
    $echo = array('message'=>$message,'code'=>$code);
    header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
    echo json_encode($echo);
}
```

**EDIT: changed $yes on the array to $message**

jquery on my view:

```
$('.jacket-btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('store/jacket'); ?>',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                    modal = $('#instructions .modal-body');
                    var child = '<span class = "note">'+res.message+'</span>';
                    modal.removeClass('instructions-content').addClass('notif');
                    $('.notif').append(child);
                    $('#instructions').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I used dataType: json as well as json_encode but I only get json object if the variables came from the else block where in there's no process before the variables. How come it only works if there's no process before the variables? Is it because of my model return?

Comment: In that nested `if` in the PHP, is `if($yes){` ever being processed?

Comment: yes, it was processed and yet the response would be like this {"message":...,"code": 900} when I console.log the response. It should be an object not responseText.

Comment: You wrong with `'message'=>$yes`. should be `'message'=>$message`

Comment: @vp_arth It should still respond with a json object not just text. $yes value is true

Comment: hm, ok... What about case when $tix < $cost but $yes is false(null/0 don't know)? Also when $tix>=$cost, $yes is not defined... and you not using your $message anywhere...

Comment: @vp_arth changed it. Still, it doesn't echo an object, just {"message": ..., "code": ...}. And when I console.log(res), I get a parsererror on the console.

Comment: take out if($yes) and try...

Comment: @carter the same.. It's not json object... I tried that first before this one, and I thought that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.

`'{"message":"Ready to redeem your mug","code":900}'` is right JSON string, but you need native js object, not json, yes?

I think your issue here:
$.ajax don't process response anyway
If you need a native JS Object use:

```
try{
  var result = JSON.parse(res);
} catch(e) {console.error(e); }
console.log(result);
```

*I dont't know what in your res can crash console.log(res), think parse error in some other place*

Comment: it's getting a parserror at first. where should i put this? i'm confused already

Comment: put all this in your `result: function(res){ "here" }` remove/comment all other code from result callback. Inspect a console.

Comment: this code has not any syntax errors: `$.ajax({
            url: '/',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(res){
                    console.log(res.substr(0, 100));
            }
        });`. Try to check it right on this page in the browser console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your controller function needs to use the CI way of json output:

```
public function redeem($item){
$this->load->model('point_model');
$cost = 0;
switch($item){
    case 'umbrella':
        $cost = 100;
        break;
    case 'jacket':
        $cost = 200;
        break;
    case 'mug':
        $cost = 50;
        break;
}
$tixD = $this->point_model->getTicks($_SESSION['playerID']);
$tix = $tixD[0]->pticks;
if($tix < $cost){
    $this->load->model('prize_model');
    $this->prize_model->setPrize($item,$_SESSION['playerID']);
    $newTix = $tix - $cost;
    $yes = $this->point_model->updateTicks($newTix,$_SESSION['playerID']);
    if($yes){
        $message = 'Ready to redeem your '.$item;
        $code = 900;
    }
}else{
    $message = 'Insufficient tickets.';
    $code = 911;
}
$echo['message'] = $message;
$echo['code'] = $code;

$this->output
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode($echo));   
}
```

Not sure, tho.

Comment: If this doesn't output anything for you this way at the client, then its definitely something going wrong in your processes and you need to debug it.

Comment: isn't it the same? header(...) is the same with ->set_content_type()?

Comment: It ought to be, but you never know when using frameworks. I use json on my CI controllers a lot and it works this way perfectly, so there its just a check to be sure.

Comment: Tried it. Still, the return is this: {"message":"Ready to redeem your mug","code":900}, and it still not a json since the ajax didn't run the success function.

Comment: then it's on my controller?